# Could breadcrumbs be considered as rich anchor text, and drop my ranking?

Tags: seo, links, rich-snippets, breadcrumbs

I have breadcrumbs on my site, and the anchor text for the links are an exact match for the keyword I want to rank for. So in other words, it's "rich" anchor text.

An example of my breadcrumbs could look like:

**Home > Apple Cheats > Apple Points Cheats > Apple Seeds Game Cheats**

Well I've also used RDF markup to construct my breadcrumbs, following the Google article [Rich snippets - Breadcrumbs](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/185417?hl=en#) which will allow Google to recognize it.

So overall, do I need to worry about exact match anchor text that will get me penalized by something like Penguin? If so, I can remove the breadcrumbs easily.

Comment: You're really over-thinking things

Comment: As John alluded to, if you focus on developing your site naturally for visitors to understand, and just avoid black-hat techniques like [keyword stuffing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyword_stuffing), as I pointed out regarding exact match keyword anchor text, you won't have to worry so much about getting penalized.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [very relevant thread from WebmasterWorld](http://www.webmasterworld.com/google/4442234.htm).

> Many webmasters will do this by placing the same term in the page title, URLs, meta tags, body text, anchor text, header tags etc etc. It is important NOT to do this. Google will know what the subject of your site is without having to repeat the same phrase over and over. That just gives a poor user experience.

This is good advice and would apply to breadcrumbs as well.   Write them to make them easy for users to read and use. That would mean that you shouldn't be so repetitive.

**Home > Apple Cheats > Points > Apple Seeds Game**

might look better to users and avoid any over optimization penalties from Google.